# TextView: wrap_content + отступ?

Tags: java, android

Делаю закругленный TextView. Использую wrap_content, но текст налазит на границы.

[image: simple]

Возможно, есть несложный способ сделать wrap_content + отступы по краям? +5dp к примеру.
ниже код.

rounded.xml:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="#C8A032" />

<corners android:radius="20dp" />

<stroke
    android:width="3dip"
    android:color="#FF5A4C24" />

</shape>
```

и кусок из основного лайаута:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `padding`.

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView10"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:paddingEnd="10dp"
     android:paddingStart="10dp"
     android:paddingTop="5dp"
     android:paddingBottom="5dp"
     android:background="@drawable/rounded"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="TextView" />
```

`margin`- это внешний отступ (снаружи от границ `View` до остальных элементов)

`padding` - это внутренний отступ (внутри от границ `View`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ. правда, у меня сработало не `android:layout_paddingEnd="10dp"` а `android:paddingEnd="10dp"`

Comment: Ну я могу ошибиться немного. Но суть передал. Ща ответ поправлю

Comment: @Oberon, так как вы используете xml-графику, то и отступы правильнее [прописать прямо в xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48548790/7566397) , через тег <inset>